# Bypass Gate-to-trigger-converter via switching jack

Tags: digital-logic, switches, audio, sample-and-hold

### Goal

I like to trigger a [LF398 Sample-and-Hold IC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lf398-n.pdf) via a 3.5mm Jack (modular synthesizer). The desired behaviour would be:

1. if **a cable is plugged in**, incoming signals will be converted to short triggers.
2. if **no cable is plugged in**, the LF398 should sample all the time (the trigger part should be essentially bypassed)

This is the way the circuit looks right now:

[image]

The sections of the circuit are described below. The simulation pictured can be found [here](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+69.34413510434165+50+5+43%0AR+96+208+16+208+4+5+40+5+0+0+0.159154943092%0Ar+224+192+224+272+0+1000%0A162+224+272+224+304+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0Ag+224+304+224+320+0%0Aw+224+192+128+192+0%0Ac+272+192+336+192+0+2.2000000000000002e-10+1.812857178472093e-36%0AO+464+192+528+192+0%0Ag+400+288+400+304+0%0Ar+336+288+336+192+0+100000%0Ag+336+288+336+304+0%0Ad+336+192+400+192+1+0.805904783%0Ad+400+288+400+192+1+0.805904783%0AS+128+192+96+192+0+0+false+0+2%0AR+96+176+96+128+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ab+64+112+155+225+0%0Ax+64+89+131+107+4+12+Switching%5C%5Cn3.5mm%5CsJack%0Aw+224+192+272+192+0%0Ab+194+113+253+354+0%0Ax+192+88+260+106+4+12+Gate%5Csdisplay%5C%5CnLED%0Ab+280+115+419+356+0%0Aw+400+192+464+192+0%0Ax+279+89+356+107+4+12+Gate%5Csto%5Cstrigger%5C%5Cnconversion%0Ab+446+116+553+245+0%0Ax+443+91+556+109+4+12+Trigger%5Csfor%5CsLF398%5C%5CnSample-and-Hold%5CsIC%0Ao+4+64+0+4099+5+0.00625+0+2+4+3%0Ao+6+64+0+4098+5+0.1+0+1%0A).

[image]

### Problem

Is there any way I can reach the goal without adding too many parts or increasing complexity? Can I switch a signal path just by this switching jack?

Maybe if I exchange the switching jack with a stereo jack and add something on the ring that switches high as it is pulled to ground?

**Edit:** lifting ground at D8 and R20 would work, but how do I switch it the way I want?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to replace the PJ301M-12 with a stereo jack and use the second contact to pull a NPN transistor's base to ground once a cable is plugged in and add offset if nothing is plugged in:
[image]
Click [here fore the simulation](http://falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+69.34413510434165+50+5+43%0AR+128+192+48+192+4+5+40+5+0+0+0.159154943092%0Ar+224+192+224+272+0+1000%0A162+224+272+224+304+1+2.1024259+1+0+0+0.01%0Ag+224+304+224+320+0%0Aw+224+192+128+192+0%0Ac+272+192+336+192+0+2.2000000000000002e-10+-4.28925538872732e-9%0AO+464+192+528+192+0%0Ar+336+288+336+192+0+100000%0Ad+336+192+400+192+1+0.805904783%0Ad+400+288+400+192+1+0.805904783%0Ax+181+-102+306+-84+4+12+Stereo%5Cs3.5mm%5C%5CnJack%5Csusing%5CsMono%5Cscable%0Aw+224+192+272+192+0%0Ab+194+113+253+354+0%0Ax+192+88+260+106+4+12+Gate%5Csdisplay%5C%5CnLED%0Ab+280+115+419+356+0%0Aw+400+192+464+192+0%0Ax+279+89+356+107+4+12+Gate%5Csto%5Cstrigger%5C%5Cnconversion%0Ab+446+116+553+245+0%0Ax+443+91+556+109+4+12+Trigger%5Csfor%5CsLF398%5C%5CnSample-and-Hold%5CsIC%0As+256+16+192+16+0+0+false%0Aw+368+304+368+288+0%0Aw+336+288+368+288+0%0Aw+368+288+400+288+0%0AR+400+-64+400+-96+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+400+-64+400+0+0+4700%0Ag+368+304+368+320+0%0Ar+304+16+352+16+0+4700%0Aw+400+64+400+192+0%0Aw+400+64+400+32+0%0Ab+166+-122+449+71+0%0Ag+192+16+192+48+0%0Aw+368+16+352+16+0%0Aw+256+16+304+16+0%0At+368+16+400+16+1+1+-1.7203735633130838e-8+-4.9999999994736+100%0Ar+304+16+304+-64+0+47000%0Aw+304+-64+400+-64+0%0Ao+4+64+0+4099+5+0.00625+0+2+4+3%0Ao+6+64+0+4098+10+0.1+0+1%0A)

This solution has the obvious downsides:

1. I need to replace the jacks
2. If a stereo cable this solution will not work anymore